# USING not equivalent to ON with an OUTER JOIN

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Why don't the following queries produce identical results?

```
with l as (select $1 id from values(1), (2), (3))
   , r as (select $1 id from values(1), (4))
select l.*,r.* from l full outer join r using(id);

ID  ID
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4

with l as (select $1 id from values(1), (2), (3))
   , r as (select $1 id from values(1), (4))
select l.*,r.* from l full outer join r on r.id = l.id;

ID  ID
1   1
2   
3   
    4
```

The [JOIN docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/join.html) say: `o1 join o2 using (key_column)` is equivalent to `o1 join o2 on o2.key_column = o1.key_column`

Answer (score 1):

I guess this falls under non-standard use, so don't do it.  Specifically:

> To use the USING clause properly, the projection list (the list of columns and other expressions after the SELECT keyword) should be “`*`”.

SparkSQL produces the same results as Snowflake, but psql produces the result I expect, so... I guess its inconsistent.

```
scala> spark.sql("with l as (select col1 id from values(1), (2), (3))   , r as (select col1 id from values(1), (4)) select * from l full outer join r using(id)").show()
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
|  3|
|  4|
|  2|
+---+


scala> spark.sql("with l as (select col1 id from values(1), (2), (3))   , r as (select col1 id from values(1), (4)) select * from l full outer join r on l.id = r.id").show()
+----+----+
|  id|  id|
+----+----+
|   1|   1|
|   3|null|
|null|   4|
|   2|null|
+----+----+


psql> with l as (select $1 id from values(1), (2), (3))
   , r as (select $1 id from values(1), (4))
select l.*,r.* from l full outer join r using(id);

id  id
1   1
2   (null)
3   (null)
(null)  4
```

Comment: What do you get when you do `SELECT *`, rather than `SELECT l.*, r.*` in Snowflake?

Comment: The same result as Spark SQL: 1-column containing id from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior looks strange indeed. The recommended approach is to use `ON`, not `USING`.

From the Snowflake community discussions:

> According to the ANSI standard,

```sql
FROM t1
FULL OUTER JOIN t2
USING (c)
```

> produces the following expressions: coalesce(t1.c, t2.c) as c . So subsequent references to t1.c and t2.c are actually not defined in the standard. MySQL, Postgres, and Snowflake all support these references, but use different semantics. In Snowflake, t1.c and t2.c are just aliases for c.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008WRZBBSA5/bug-with-join-using-